# unique contraint violation in update-from statement

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have following query:

```
UPDATE "PostsTags"
SET "TagId" = "PostsTags"."TagId" #tgs."mainId"
FROM (
  SELECT t1."TagId" AS "mainId", t1.text AS "mainText", t2."TagId" AS "malformedId", t2.text AS "malformedText"
  FROM "TagTranslations" t1 
  INNER JOIN "TagTranslations" t2 ON t1.text = regexp_replace(t2.text, '^\s+','') AND t2.id != t1.id
  WHERE regexp_replace(t1.text, '^\s+','') = t1.text AND t1."language" = 'en-us'
) tgs
WHERE "PostsTags"."TagId" = tgs."malformedId" AND "PostsTags"."language" = 'en-us' AND "PostsTags"."PostId" = 281
RETURNING *
```

As you can see I am updating `TagId = TagId` (I am setting same value to TagId column). I am getting following error:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PostsTags_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (language, "PostId", "TagId")=(en-us, 281, 10157) already exists.
```

Can someone tell me how it is possible that I am receiving this violations while I am not actually changing anything?

Comment: What is that bit "#tgs..." doing? `SET "TagId" = "TagId" #tgs."mainId"`

Comment: You are updating `TagId` with the value from the subquery. So that can definitely cause duplicates.

Comment: `#tgs."mainId"` is just comment. I am just setting TagId to its previous value so how it may lead to violation?

Comment: It might not be obvious from the query, but you are setting `TagID` from the subquery, otherwise you would have to set it to `PostsTags.TagId`

Comment: I changed it to `"PostsTags"."TagId"` and I receive same error - this is crazy!

Comment: `#` **does not introduce a comment**. It is the bitwise `XOR` operator. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-math.html

Comment: WOOT - you are right! thank you! If you will add answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#` does not introduce a comment. It is the bitwise XOR operator. [The manual](http://postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-math.html)

For comments that end on the end of line, use `-- THIS Is a Comment`

```
UPDATE "PostsTags"
SET "TagId" = "PostsTags"."TagId" -- COMMENTED OUT: tgs."mainId"
FROM (
  SELECT t1."TagId" AS "mainId", t1.text AS "mainText", t2."TagId" AS "malformedId", t2.text AS "malformedText"
  FROM "TagTranslations" t1 
  INNER JOIN "TagTranslations" t2 ON t1.text = regexp_replace(t2.text, '^\s+','') AND t2.id != t1.id
  WHERE regexp_replace(t1.text, '^\s+','') = t1.text AND t1."language" = 'en-us'
) tgs
WHERE "PostsTags"."TagId" = tgs."malformedId" AND "PostsTags"."language" = 'en-us' AND "PostsTags"."PostId" = 281
-- RETURNING *
  ;
```

BTW: there is still no guarantee that the update is correct; the subquery *could* result in more than one matching tuple being returned for a given `t2.TagId` --> `tgs."malformedId"` --> `"postTags"."TagId"`